# Convolutional neural network with 1 channel images/1 input channel

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, convolution

I'm following a [tutorial on tensorflow using a convolutional neural network](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn) for images, but I'm looking to do it with grayscale images. How would the code posted there be different if it was for grayscale images instead of colored images with 3 channels?

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will be the updated code for grayscale images:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
```

**Why?**

Because for an RGB image, there are 3 channels, 'R', 'G' and 'B'
So, the input shape will be `(height, width, 3)`

But since grayscale has only one channel, the input shape becomes `(height, width, 1)`

Note that if you are using Keras with Tensorflow backend, then the data_format is `channels_last`, which means that the input shape should be  `(height, width, channels)`.

Otherwise, if you are using Theano as the backend, then the input shape should be `(channels, height, width)` since Theano uses the `channels_first` data format.

Hope this is of help.
Please upvote if helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))`

*will become*

```py
 input_shape=(32, 32, 1)))
```

Channel is the last argument by default

*"...When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide the keyword argument input_shape (tuple of integers, does not include the sample axis), e.g. input_shape=(128, 128, 3) for 128x128 RGB pictures in data_format="channels_last..."*

[Ref - *Keras Docs*](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/)